# sudo NOPASSWD for particular paths

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

How can I enable `NOPASSWD` for a user to do anything in several paths?

For instance read/write/execute any file in `/etc/init.d` and `/opt/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following at the end of your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
username ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/*,/opt/*
```